# Как правильно выйти из цикла (параллельные запросы)

Tags: golang

```
package main

type Result struct{}

func main() {
    // не более 100 одновременных запросов?
    ch = make(chan Result, 100)
    // Тут мы как бы читаем csv-файл построчно, не весь сразу в память, потому как
    // там миллионы записей
    for /* тут получаем  row */ {
        go func() {
            // Отправляем в канал результат
            ch <- Result
        }()
    }
    // И тут мы читаем данные из канала
    // Тут как бы вечный цикл
    for {
            res := <-ch
            // Что-то делаем с результатом
            // И вот вопрос как выйти из этого цикла?
            // Использовать счетчик? - Завести переменную results и делать что-то типа:
            // results -= 1
            // if (results == 0) {
            //  break
            // }
            // мне кажется он так преждевременно выйдет из цикла. не?
            // либо завести еще один канал и ждать пока тот вернет false/true и выходить
            // из цикла
    }
}
```

При использовании переменной счетчика возможно преждевременное завершение приложения? Или только с дополнительным каналом рабочий результат либо есть еще варианты? Как принято делать в go (мой опыт в go: одна книга прочитанная вдоль и онлайн-туториал).

Comment: По-моему вам нужен [`sync.WaitGroup`](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup).

Comment: мне не известно количество запросов, которые необходимо сделать

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы обработка данных шла одновременно с их получением, или после?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/codedumps/31a12e198d823e3a4203e1b09a2bed57  такой код набросал. не важно после или одновременно, я не знаю как цикл остановить когда ссылки в файле кончатся. go одновременно легкий и одновременно непонятный.

Answer (score 1):

Ваша задача легко решается [`sync.WaitGroup`](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup). [Пример](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/sync/#example_WaitGroup) в документации буквально описывает конкретно ваш случай:

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
var urls = []string{
    "http://www.golang.org/",
    "http://www.google.com/",
    "http://www.somestupidname.com/",
}
for _, url := range urls {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(url string) {
        defer wg.Done()
        http.Get(url)
    }(url)
}
wg.Wait()
```

Вам всего лишь надо класть куда-то результаты. Например в канал (закрыв его после `wg.Wait()`), либо в слайс, давая каждой горутине свой индекс.

Comment: а зачем тут defer wg.Done(). Я знаю что он откладывает выполнение кода. Но зачем?

Comment: Чтобы он выполнился в любом случае. Иначе `Wait()` заблочит навсегда.